# The latest examples of civil engineering projects with great mathematical content

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, applications

Maybe the distribution of lands after the Nile's Inundation was the first civil engineering project involving mathematics (notions of geometry) 
for its development.

In this post I am asking about civil (and not religious) engineering projects similar to buildings, bridges, highways,... Not similar to airplanes, ships, air turbines, computers, engines...

**Examples from Roman engineering.** I know from the literature how it's fascinating, for example, the shape of the Colosseum or the accuracy on the slope in the Aqueduct of Segovia. I refer these examples because Roman engineering was/is as a model for civil engineering.

> **Question.** But, what are the latest (in the last 5 or 10 years) examples of civil engineering projects with great mathematical content? I am asking about of civil engineering projects whose development should be impossible without remarkable mathematics, and/or well because these projects incorporate remarkable elements from mathematics. **Thanks in advance.**

**Updated after comment:** I mean projects with mathematical content much 
 greater in comparison than a common engineering project.

Comment: Every civil engineering project has great/remarkable mathematical content. I think you have to be a little more precise.

Comment: I accept your critic but now I don't know how be more precise with this question. Many thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: Non-government organizations, for example Mr. Elon Musk's companies, are now developing rockets for space travel and for the deployment of satellites.  I imagine this is as "math intensive" as government-backed space programs.

Comment: I was thinking in projects similar to buildings, bridges, highways,... Any case this is an invitation if you want to expand your answer, explaining 
briefly, and always from an informative viewpoint, what kind of mathematics should be required in the developing of rockets, if there are some novelty in the field of mathematics or remarkable comparison with other mathematical technique in the design of rockets (I am saying if it is public). Many thanks @DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly noted in the comments, there are lots of civil engineering projects with remarkable mathematical content. Some of them could be even trivial to be cited, since they can be easily found even in the Guinness book of world records. However, I would cite three non-trivial examples of engineering projects, which in my opinion involved particularly important mathematical content:

- The [Water Discus Hotel](http://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/space-age-underwater-hotel-maldives/index.html) (2017), a luxury resort set to be built on the tropical island of Kuredhivaru in the Maldive Islands. Its body resembles that of a spaceship above the water, hold by five spidery legs plunging deep into the sea. Such a futuristic project required remarkable mathematical content with additional issues as compared to structures built on the land, e.g. in the chemistry and physics fundamental to provide long-term water resistance, the technical calculations to ensure architectural stability for legs that are inserted in the seabed, the modeling and simulations to predict the behaviour of the building exposed to sea currents/tides and atmospheric winds, and so on;
- The 57 km long [Gotthard Base Tunnel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotthard_Base_Tunnel) (2016), recently built beneath the Swiss/Italian Alps under the Gotthard massif. Compared to standard tunnels, this base tunnel required significant mathematical content because of the several issues related its unusual, deep "base" nature, which include the need to study the best geometry of the tunnel and the best materials to bear the impressive weight of the overlying rock, the need to develop accurate models for the ventilation system and the temperature regulation, and so on;
- The [Venice MOSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSE_Project) (still to be completed), a project aimed at protecting the city of Venice, Italy, from flooding, characterized by an integrated system consisting of rows of mobile gates. It is well known that this megaproject has been obstacled by a number of problems, among which considerable cost overruns, delays, and claims of inadequacy. Regardless of this, it is undoubtful that the development of the underlying control systems required important mathematical implications, mostly applied to simulation procedures. These were related to the need of forecasting high waters, defining warning systems and barrier raising/lowering decision-making processes, and modelling the hydraulic effects of virtual gate manoeuvres.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very good. And thanks to the users commenting previously.